# Questions about distributed finetuning of transformers model (chatglm) with Accelerate in Kaggle GPUs

Tags: huggingface-transformers, kaggle, large-language-model, peft, fine-tuning

I am trying to finetune the chatglm-6b model using LoRA with transformers and peft in Kaggle GPUs (2*T4). The model structure:

[image: model]

The traditional loading method (AutoModel.from_pretrained) needs to load the model itself (15 GB) onto CPU first, whereas the CPU memory in Kaggle is 13 GB and the model cannot be loaded.

Thus, I used load_checkpoint_and_dispatch() function of Accelerate to load the model:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel, AutoConfig
from accelerate import load_checkpoint_and_dispatch, init_empty_weights
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download

FilePath = snapshot_download(repo_id='THUDM/chatglm-6b')

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(FilePath, load_in_8bit=True, trust_remote_code=True)
with init_empty_weights():
    model = AutoModel.from_config(config, trust_remote_code=True).half()
model = load_checkpoint_and_dispatch(
    model, FilePath, device_map='auto', no_split_module_classes=["GLMBlock"]
)
```

With this method the model can be loaded successfully in both CPU and GPUs.
[image: memory]

Then the LoRA adapters were added with peft.

```
from peft import get_peft_model, LoraConfig, TaskType

peft_config = LoraConfig(
    task_type=TaskType.CAUSAL_LM,
    inference_mode=False, r=32, lora_alpha=32, lora_dropout=0.1, bias='none',
    # ['dense','dense_h_to_4h','dense_4h_to_h'] # 'query_key_value',
    target_modules=['query_key_value',],
)
model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)
```

Now, the model can generate output directly with

```
outputs = model(**tokenizer(['Hello world!'], return_tensors='pt).to(model.device))
```

However, after using accelerator.prepare() to wrap the model, dataloader, etc, I got the RuntimeError.

```
accelerator = Accelerator()

train_dataloader, val_dataloader, model, optimizer = \
        accelerator.prepare(train_dataloader, val_dataloader, model, optimizer)
```

```
train_loss = []
epoch_correct_num, epoch_total_num = 0, 0
model.train()
for batch in tqdm(train_dl):
        labels = batch['labels']
        outputs = model(**batch)
        loss, logits = outputs.loss, outputs.logits
        optim.zero_grad()
#         loss.backward()
        accelerator.backward(loss)
        grad_norm = torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 2.0)
        optim.step()
        scheduler.step()
```

[image: error]

Are there some methods to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?